# Get INT from a Serial tram in arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, integer

I'm trying to analyse a received trame from Serial in my Arduino Code.

I receive a trame like : ACTION=24:A2:D1:8F:38:28=12

I know how to divid the 3 part in string. I've got now one string with ACTION one string with the MAC ADDRESS and one last string with the last value after last "=".

But I want to convert the last value after the "=" to an INT.

My code is :

```cpp
if (Serial.available()) {
  Serial.println("Recpetion en cours");

  c = Serial.readString();
  sixFirstChar = c.substring(0, 6);
  Serial.println(c);
  Serial.println(sixFirstChar);
  if (sixFirstChar == "ACTION" || sixFirstChar == "SAVING" || sixFirstChar == "MASTER") {
    ActionAccRqst = c.substring(7,24);
    ActionToSend = c.substring(25,c.length());
    Serial.println("Une action est à envoyer à : ");
    Serial.print(ActionAccRqst);
    Serial.print(" -> ");
    Serial.println(ActionToSend);

    if (sixFirstChar == "ACTION") {
      myData.Type = 1;
    } else if (sixFirstChar == "SAVING") {
      myData.Type = 2;
    } else if (sixFirstChar == "MASTER") {
      myData.Type = 10;
    }

    myData.Message = ActionToSend.toInt();

    Serial.println(myData.Type);
    Serial.println(myData.Message);
  }
}
```

I've tried with `toInt()` where myData.Message is defined as a Long but my SerialPrint return always 0 ...

Comment: tram, trame?  what do you mean?

Comment: there should be houndreds of tutorials on how to convert numbers and strings or parts of them back and forth online btw.

Comment: Try doing the same with assigning to int (instead of long).

Comment: @YigalB, Both the same result with int or long...